# Array.push(Object) inserts array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm currently trying to read the days of absence of my colleague from our excel files and store them in a mongodb using mongoose and express-js.

Reading the data works fine, but updating the data in the db always produces the strange behavior, where inserting an Object into an array using Array.push() results in an Array of Objects containing a single object inside the outer array.

The function below gets the raw data from the excel files and attempts to store them in the db. Please ignore the code-mess, I was just prototyping ;-)

```
function getDaysOff( data, callback )
{
    Member.find({}, function( err, docs ) {
        if ( err )
        {
            console.error( err );
            return [];
        }
        console.log( "found " + docs.length + " team members" );
        docs.forEach( function( element ) {
            // reset all arrays befor continuing
            element.days_of_absence = [];
        } );
        data.forEach( function( element ) {
            for ( let i = 0; i < element.length; ++i )
            {
                var member = element[i];
                for ( let j = 0; j < docs.length; ++j )
                {   
                    if ( member.name.match( new RegExp( docs[j].name, 'g' ) ) )
                    {
                        console.log( member.name + " is " + docs[j].name );
                        for ( let k = 0;  k < member.absent.length; ++k )
                        {
                            docs[j].days_of_absence.push( member.absent[k] );
                            console.log( JSON.stringify( member.absent[k] ) );
                        }
                        console.log( JSON.stringify( docs[j].days_of_absence ) );
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } );
        docs.forEach( function( element ) {
            element.save();
        } );
        callback( docs );
    });
}
```

And here is the Member schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')  
var MemberSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
            _id: {
                        type: 'ObjectId'
                    },
            name: {
                        type: 'String'
                    },
            prename: {
                        type: 'String'
                    },
            days_of_absence: {
                        type: 'Array'
                    }
    }
);
module.exports =  mongoose.model('Member', MemberSchema, 'members');
```

When printing `days_of_absence` it yields something like this:

```
[
  [ { "date": "2018-01-28T23:00:00.000Z", "reason": "P" } ],
  [ { "date": "2018-01-29T23:00:00.000Z", "reason": "P" } ],
  ...
  [ { "date": "2018-09-27T22:00:00.000Z", "reason": "P" } ]
]
```

Where `members.absent[k]` is equal to the objects inside the inner array. (I already checked that).
However I have no clue where the arrays around the objects come from. What am I missing? What I want is some like this:

```
[
  { "date": "2018-01-28T23:00:00.000Z", "reason": "P" },
  { "date": "2018-01-29T23:00:00.000Z", "reason": "P" },
  ...
  { "date": "2018-09-27T22:00:00.000Z", "reason": "P" }
]
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested I already tested if `member.absent[k]` is an array however printing it in the loop revealed that it isn't. `console.log( member.absent[k] )` yields the desired:

```
{"date":"2018-09-02T22:00:00.000Z","reason":"P"}
```

Comment: `member.absent[k]` must be an array then.

Comment: `for ( let k = 0;  k < member.absent.length; ++k )` why are you skipping the first entry? (`++k` instead of `k++`)

Comment: @connexo I didn't know that `++k` would skip the first entry. Coming from C++ it's just a natural thing to use pre increment over post increment.

Comment: @connexo, the `for` loop does **not** rely on post or pre fix at the incremention part. the start and condition part is right, so the array should loop from zero to lenght - 1.

Comment: @NinaScholz Can you add reference for that? Thanks for correcting me. For the sake of readability and to avoid false conclusions like mine, I'd still recommend to use k++ over ++k.

Comment: for sake of speed, you might use `++k`, because prefix is faster, just because of the synchon incrementing and retuning the last value instead of storing the value, increment and return the stored value of the expression.

Comment: @Nina could a compiler optimize this?

Comment: @Sandro, it could, but i would not rely on it.

Comment: @Nina but in a sense you are relying on it not unoptimizing the `++k` statement, right?

Comment: @Sandro, right. `++k` is optimized.

Comment: I personally wouldn't change something like this for performance reasons, but interesting to see how it could make a difference.

Comment: it's just micro optimization that comes from C/C++. But even in C++ it makes difference if the operator has been overridden or depends on compiler. That's why it's said to use prefix if you don't have specific reason to use postfix. I don't think it matters for javascript, because chome for example preferes postfix

Answer (score 2):

It looks like, you have an array for `member.absent[k]`. You could spread it and get a single object.

```
docs[j].days_of_absence.push(...member.absent[k]);
```

I you do not know if the value is always an array, you could make one and spread it.

```
docs[j].days_of_absence.push(...(
    Array.isArray(member.absent[k])
        ? member.absent[k]
        : [member.absent[k]]
));
```

Comment: `+1` - just make sure `member.absent[k]` is indeed an array in **all** cases, otherwise you'll get an error

Comment: @Adelin An object would work, too. `docs[j].days_of_absence.push({...member.absent[k]});`

Comment: However, (have a look at my Edit) `member.absent[k]` ain't no array. That's why i can't understand where the error comes from.

Comment: @muXXmit2X, that's quite interesting. somehow do you get an extra array.